# Can Muramana's active ever proc twice on one attack?

Tags: league-of-legends

Is it possible for Muramana's active to proc twice on one single-target attack? For example, Poppy's Devastating Blow (Q) or Twisted Fate's Pick a Card (W) add an effect to the following autoattack. On the next autoattack, the spell is used and on-hit effects are applied. Do these abilities, or any other ability, allow Muramana to activate twice?

Comment: So... like Shyvana's Q or Warwick's Ult? I'm not sure I understand what scenario you're trying to trigger.

Comment: Shyvana's Q would be the only case I'd consider it possible, as the attack is actually 2 strikes with on-hit effects.

Comment: Hm. I think your question is actually, "Do auto-attack modifying abilities trigger Muramana twice?"

Comment: No, I'm asking if any single-target attack can ever proc muramana twice. Whether it's an AA-modifying ability I don't care. Just interested if there are any cases.

Comment: Warwick's Q would be one tick as well, amiright?

Answer (score 5):

While certain abilities (like Draven's Spinning Axe, Mordekaiser's Mace of Spades, or Twisted Fate's Pick a Card) modify your auto-attack, their effect triggers as *part* of the auto-attack, not as an additional effect.

Therefore, Muramana does not trigger once for the ability AND once for the auto-attack, because, for these abilities, the auto-attack *is* the ability.

Likewise, abilities that cause on-hit effects (such as Ezreal's Mystic Shot or Gangplank's Parrrley) only trigger Muramana once. Abilities that cause multiple on-hit effects (such as Warwick's Infinite Duress) trigger Muramana once per "hit", but do not get an additional trigger from the fact that it is a single-target spell.

Comment: Coming back to this question; this is actually completely incorrect. For example, Jax can proc muramana 3 times with his ult passive proc and his W. Poppy procs Muramana twice with her Q. Those are the only champs I tested.

Comment: @Gus Neither Jax's ult nor Poppy's Q modify function in the same way as Ezreal's or Gangplank's. In those cases, there is a separate effect, **in addition to** the auto-attack, rather than a simple replacement, like Parrrley or Mystic Shot.

Comment: @Gus Poppy's Q in particular is a weird mishmash of exception cases. It doesn't quite count as an auto-attack, and it's not quite a spell, either.

Answer (score 3):

Being that those abilities are on hit effects and muramana is an on hit effect. No.

On hit effects stack with eachother but for no reason will they double proc. I don't remember if Muramana is a CD, but it definitly only procs once per hit.

Now if you wanna talk about spells that make your champion attack more than once, then thats a whole different story.